# Multiple expandable list views not scrollable

Tags: android, scrollview, expandablelistview

I have a Problem by my App.
In a loop I dynamically create an ExpandableListView. Now I want to make my screen scrollable. 
But when i put a Scrollview over my Layout, the screen will not able to scroll and the expandable list views are very tiny. How can I fix this?

---

No i have to scroll the Screen with the ExpandableListViews.

When i have more Customers or i turn the Phone, the Screen will be to small and so i have to Scroll, but it will not works.
Thanks Mark

My screen looks like:

```
+-------------------------------------+
|                                     |
|  Customer 1:                        |
|  +-------------------------------+  |
|  |                               +  |
|  |    ExpandableListView 1       +  |
|  |                               +  |
|  +-------------------------------+  |
|                                     |
|                                     |
|  Customer 2:                        |
|  +-------------------------------+  |
|  |                               +  |
|  |    ExpandableListView 2       +  |
|  |                               +  |
|  +-------------------------------+  |
|                                     |
|                                     |
|  Customer 3:                        |
|  +-------------------------------+  |
|  |                               +  |
|  |    ExpandableListView 3       +  |
|  |                               +  |
|  +-------------------------------+  |
|                                     |
|                                     |
|                                     |
+-------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Have you figured out the problem? Im kind of stuck in the same problem, would like to know how you solved it.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say without seeing the code, but it sounds like your list item view are small enough to not need to bee scrolled through. FWIW you don't need a scroll view for a `ListView` or `ExpandableListView` as they both scroll on their own.